# regex doesn't work with optional ()? sentense

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I try to get all files like scheme_12.sql and scheme_23_analytics.sql from folder with bash and regex works in a strange way in terminal, doesn't return anything. Also checked in python re and some interactive regex sites. It works.

my command `ls | find . -type f -regex "\.\/scheme_[0-9]+_([a-zA-Z]+)?.sql"`

but command without optional sentence works `ls | find . -type f -regex "\.\/scheme_[0-9]+.sql"`

I have no idea why. Can you help me find a mistake?

Comment: What do you get from `find -regextype help`?

Comment: What do you hope that piping `ls` to `find` should accomplish? The `ls` is a no-op, as `find` will simply ignore its standard input. [You should generally not use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The default regex type doesn't support the construct. Use `-regextype` to specify a different one, `posix-extended` if available for example should support it.

Also, why do you pipe the output of `ls` to `find`? `find` doesn't need anything from standard input.

```
$ touch scheme_12.sql  scheme_23_analytics.sql
$ find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex "\.\/scheme_[0-9]+_([a-zA-Z]+)?.sql"
./scheme_23_analytics.sql
```

To get both the files back, you need to move the underscore inside the optional character class.

Comment: Thank you for answer. it was my typo only in this example with underscore outside the optional character class. removed ls and added regextype to command but it doesn't work too

Comment: found out a solution by  adding "\" before  underscore inside optional character class

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Can you post the command that worked for you? Did you try copying my example verbatim?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

- You are using POSIX BRE pattern where the group syntax is `\(...\)`, not `(...)` and `+` quantifier is usually written either as `\{1,\}` or re-written from `a+` to `aa*`
- The `([a-zA-Z]+)?` part is equal to `[a-zA-Z]*`, and the underscore in front is still *obligatory*. You need to make the whole *sequence*  of `_` and letters optional
- Literal dot before `sql` must be escaped, or it will match any char
- The `/` char does not need to be escaped in `find` regex because it does not use regex delimiters.

Here is a POSIX ERE solution:

```sh
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '\./scheme_[0-9]+(_[[:alpha:]]+)?\.sql'
```

So, `(_[[:alpha:]]+)?` here defines an optional sequence of `_` and one or more letters.